# git Master with multiple duplicated projects

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a **Master** Project in Xcode.

- I have duplicated projects of Master with some changes.
- I am using Visual Studio online as Git Repo.
- New Changes on Master has to apply for the duplicated oprojects, at
  the same   time i have to keep the chages of every projects.

  > **How can i handle all the branches of Master as the indivual projects?**

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making changes on `master`, you will want to merge master into each of your individual project branches. So let's say your project branches are called `p1` and `p2`; you would want to do:

```
git checkout p1
git merge master
git checkout p2
git merge master
```

Comment: *So merge does not effect the Code of P1 /P2 , I mean some individual features which i already have in P1 / P2? or it will be deleted in new version? *

Comment: Well, it will affect the code in the sense that it will bring in changes from master. However, new code in p1/p2 will not be deleted. Now, if there is code that has changed in both p1 and master since their last common ancestor, then you may get a conflict, which you will have to resolve manually.